# Using inheritance in Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance

i have two tables in DB: Foo and Bar

Using Entity Framework i want to create base entity which will contain properties which both tables have.

For example Foo has columns Id,CreateDate,FooValue and Bar has Id,CreateDate,BarValue

- So BaseEntity should have Id and CreateDate properties
- Foo should inherit BaseEntity and have FooValue
- Bar should inherit BaseEntity and have BarValue

How to map properties to their tables in DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want [Table per Concrete Type (TPC)](https://web.archive.org/web/20160610093347/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2007/03/15/inheritance-in-the-entity-framework.aspx) - here is a [blog post with a walkthrough](https://web.archive.org/web/20130515020058/http://blogs.microsoft.co.il:80/blogs/gilf/archive/2010/01/25/table-per-concrete-type-inheritance-in-entity-framework.aspx). One could also think about modifing the tables and using Table per Type (TPT) but I think this would be a bad decision for columns like `CreationDate` because you will get one table containing the creation dates from all tables.